# What is entity framework designer? Why it is used in the Model-first approach?

Tags: entity-framework

I know entity framework designer is used to create the classes of model-first approach and then we create the database by using that class. But in code-first appraoch, it is possible to create the custom classes, within that classes the database is created automatically. Then what is the difference between code-first approach and model-first approach?

Answer (score 0):

Code First is the more modern style of working with Entity Framework. As the name implies, you write the code first and the database model is generated for you, by using Entity Framework Migrations. In this scenario you are not using any graphical tool at all, everything is just pure code.

Model first means creating the abstract database model in the designer. The code is then generated by templates. If you update the model, the code will be regenerated.

Comment: this is fine. I am already studied this and also used the code-first approach and Enable-Migrations topic. But, how to differentiate the coding for code-first approach and model-first approach give any example with coding?